# Can I have two submit buttons in one form?

Tags: forms

I want to provide 2 buttons in one form. User click either button can submit the form but do different jobs-- one button is to import checked files,  another button is to create fiels. Will this confuse Wordpress?

Comment: Just re-read your question. I had close voted this, but I think it's legit.

Comment: Please rework your question. Currently it's "confuse? Why? No! It's machine & code!". :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're placing a button in a meta box, it is included within the FORM tags for a post. A simple answer is no, you shouldn't place a submit button in the post form. However, nstead of using a normal `input[type=submit]`, use the following:

```
<button type='button' name='button-name' id='button-id'>Button Text</button>'
```

A click won't process as a submit action, it will just click. You obviously will need to bind the click event to however you're importing your file list. If you're not using AJAX, you should. Check out [this article](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins&ei=6Q03UMHULOW30gG07IGIDQ&usg=AFQjCNGHXGd9iTZWc5fWi-F311d5QqDszQ&sig2=DUmVZs5H6Y68A6VEOrHvjg) on how to use AJAX in WordPress.

Having a submit button within the form will post to post.php and certainly will have unwanted effects, namely losing any changed data within the post form.

Comment: It's not metabox in post-form. It's a custom form with workdpress submit_button()

Comment: You can have two separate submit buttons. You will just need to sniff the button names in the $_POST data as the submit button will register a key in the $_POST array.

Comment: How to "sniff" the button names into $_Post data? When the form submitted, I will evalueate..."if(isset($_POST['bla'])", is that enough? Or I have to evaluate which button submitted the form?

Comment: Yes. That should work fine.